# php INSERT INTO issue with syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

```
INSERT INTO Departments (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, Location, Phone, Chair)
VALUES (50, ‘Archival Information’, ‘B479’, 4321, ‘Robin’);
```

This works, but this does not:

```
INSERT INTO Departments (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, Location, Phone, Chair)
VALUES (50, ‘Archival Information’, ‘B479’, 4321, ‘Robin’),
(51, ‘Information Retrieval’, ‘B431’, 4322, ‘Sheela’),
(52, ‘Information Organization’, ‘B410’, 4323, ‘Craig’),
(53, ‘Information Policy’ ‘B204’, 4324, ‘Michael’),
(54, ‘Information Management’, ‘B219’, 4331, ‘Chris’),
(55, ‘Information Security’, ‘B225’, 4332, ‘Steve’),
(56, ‘Information Technology’, ‘B435’, 4333, ‘Arthur’),
(57, ‘Information Design’, ‘B300’, 4334, ‘Amy’),
(58, ‘Health Informatics’, ‘B428’, 4330, ‘Rav’),
(59, ‘Information Ethics’, ‘B356’, 4320, ‘Simon’);
```

What's the problem? I've checked syntax online and this is how I've noted the proper syntax is typed out.

Comment: Don't think you can have comma separated statements like that. Try changing the comma separating the SQL statements to a semicolon ;

Comment: What error does it give you? The syntax looks fine, so it's probably related to invalid data.

Comment: @Maximus2012 What makes you say that?  Of course you can insert multiple with a single statement.  The documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: I made this attempt and received error:

Error
SQL query:

( 51, ‘Information Retrieval’, ‘B431’, 4322, ‘Sheela’ ) ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '51, â€˜Information Retrievalâ€™, â€˜B431â€™, 4322, â€˜Sheelaâ€™)' at line 1

Comment: @Brad yes you can do that but I am not sure if you can where individual statements are separated by comma and not a semicolon.

Comment: Please show *the whole* error message

Comment: @Maximus2012 What are you talking about?  There's a single `INSERT INTO` statement here.

Comment: @Brad I see what you are saying. My bad.

Comment: @John I edited the comment containing the error to display the entire error message.

Comment: It looks like you have some "fancy" quotes in your code. Is that in the actual source?

Comment: @Morgander Are you quotes really left/right "smart quotes" or are they actually quotes?

Comment: @Morgander can you make sure you are using the correct single quote (') (The one under " on the keyboard) ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Yes sir. I even went back just now and did a Replace to replace anything that might not have been a proper single quote into the single quote located beneath the double quotes on the keyboard and then tried it again to make sure.

This is the new error:

 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Informationâ€™, â€˜B479â€™, 4321, â€˜Robinâ€™), (51, â€˜Information Retrieval' at line 2

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated code then. In the current version of your question, looks like the quotes are not correct.

Comment: @Morgander please try my code, i just updated.

Comment: @EngineerCoder I did that, and it worked. Very important to me is what you did exactly that made this work. This is for a college course and my instructor gave me the syntax that I was using, so I am very confused why his syntax did not work.

Comment: Not at all @Morgander, have a nice day.

Comment: Could somebody help me answer a supplementary question? I do not understand how to get the ' opposed to the single quote that shows up in my code...

No matter what I do, my source code shows my single quotes differently than the code that EngineerCoder provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single quotes are not correct except first one

> BTW your sql server is important only mssql 2008 or newer  and mysql 
>   4.1 or newer supports inserting more then one value with comma separating.

**The correct sql query :**

```
INSERT INTO Departments (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, Location, Phone, Chair)
VALUES (50, 'Archival Information', 'B479', 4321, 'Robin'),
(51, 'Information Retrieval', 'B431', 4322, 'Sheela'),
(52, 'Information Organization', 'B410', 4323, 'Craig'),
(53, 'Information Policy', 'B204', 4324, 'Michael'),
(54, 'Information Management', 'B219', 4331, 'Chris'),
(55, 'Information Security', 'B225', 4332, 'Steve'),
(56, 'Information Technology', 'B435', 4333, 'Arthur'),
(57, 'Information Design', 'B300', 4334, 'Amy'),
(58, 'Health Informatics', 'B428', 4330, 'Rav'),
(59, 'Information Ethics', 'B356', 4320, 'Simon');
```

@exussum warn me about the mysql version so,
I edited supported mysql version number 5.5 to 4.1 thank you.

Comment: its a mysql question and the comma seperator has been around for more than 5.5+, in fact since at least version 4.1 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert.html

Comment: yes @exussum you are right, i just checked and edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma on line four of values (between `'Information Policy'` and `'B204'`). After correcting this it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
VALUES (50, 'Archival Information', 'B479', 4321, 'Robin'),
(51, ‘Information Retrieval’, ‘B431’, 4322, ‘Sheela’),
```

your first line used a single quote, while your second used backticks.

In MySQL the backtick is the `identifier quote` meaning it treats the inside as an identifier. for example a table name. a regular quote is treated as data to be inserted.

Convert line 2 on wards to use `'` instead of '`'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: I did not use the backtick on my keyboard though. The backtick shows up as `, not '. When I type a single quote on my keyboard in this comment section for instance, it doesn't even show the same single quote as is shown in the example from my original code that you've displayed here. I'm quite confused.

Comment: ok, BigBobs answer is correct then, With the missing comma

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT INTO Departments (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, Location, Phone, Chair)
VALUES 
    (50, 'Archival Information', 'B479', 4321, 'Robin'),
    (51, 'Information Retrieval', 'B431', 4322, 'Sheela'),
    (52, 'Information Organization', 'B410', 4323, 'Craig'),
    (53, 'Information Policy', 'B204', 4324, 'Michael'),
    (54, 'Information Management', 'B219', 4331, 'Chris'),
    (55, 'Information Security', 'B225', 4332, 'Steve'),
    (56, 'Information Technology', 'B435', 4333, 'Arthur'),
    (57, 'Information Design', 'B300', 4334, 'Amy'),
    (58, 'Health Informatics', 'B428', 4330, 'Rav'),
    (59, 'Information Ethics', 'B356', 4320, 'Simon');
```

Comment: How is that not what's there?

Comment: his first row is different than the rest, quotes are different

Comment: You were right and I corrected that but it still will not enter the data.

Comment: have you ran the code i just edited?

Comment: @J Hock Yes sir, and it no longer gave me the same error. Now it gives me the following error:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 4

Your quotes are different than mine and I'm using the ones under the " on the keyboard. I guess I don't understand what the true culprit here is.